# Vue Setting A Method Name Based on a Prop Value?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Is it possible to set the name of a Method in my Vue application based on the value of a prop? So my Vue Application looks like:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'CheckboxFilter',
  props: {
    tax: '',
    identifier: 'Category'
  }
}
</script>
```

Then in my Methods I want to name a method based on the value of the identifier prop.

```
methods: {
    updateSelected + this.identifier (e) {
      this.$store.commit('updateSelectedCategories', e.target.value)
    }
  }
```

Is something like this possible to do where the name of the method is influenced by the value of a prop?

EDIT: the reason why I am trying to do this is I have a component that has checkbox input filters. The layout of this component will always be the same the only difference will be the values present on those checkboxes. I need to keep track of which checkboxes are select independently from each component. So my thought for doing this is to pass an identifier prop to use as a naming convention for the method where I store the value of the selected checkboxes for each component independently in my Vuex store.

Comment: why would you want to do that? Just use the "identifier" where you need it in the method

Comment: @Derek Pollard I am trying to use one component that has a similar method each time that component is used. This is all in an attempt to modualerize a Vue application to be used based on the circumstance. The only time the identifier prop is used in the method is for the name of that method. The identifier prop is not used for anything else in that specific method.

Comment: If it's only used for the name of the method, I'd wager you don't need it then

Comment: @DerekPollard I need it so the name of the method can be unique based upon the identifier prop for that specific component. That way in my Vuex store I can use the unique method.

Comment: so then pass that into your vuex commit as an argument

Comment: @DerekPollard Oh that makes sense. Not sure why I was trying to do it this backwards way instead of just passing it as an argument. It's been a long day at work. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem! sometimes, all you need is another perspective!

Answer (score 0):

Instead, pass it as an argument to your vuex store:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    attribute: {
      tag: true,
      bag: false
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setAttr(state, { value, attribute }) {
      state.attribute[attribute] = value;
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('custom-checkbox', {
  props: ['attribute'],
  template: '<div><input type="checkbox" v-model="checkBox">{{attribute}}</div>',
  computed: {
    checkBox: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.attribute[this.attribute]
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit('updateMessage', {
          value,
          attribute: this.attribute
        });
      }
    }
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  template: '<div><custom-checkbox attribute="tag" /><custom-checkbox attribute="bag" /></div>'
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.0/vuex.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

That way, you're not trying to rely on dynamic data in your static code.